# passing string to Audio()

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code to play an audio file. Ths is the place I take mp3 url

```
$(mp3link).append($("<textarea name="+"mp3link"+" id=\"mp33\" rows="+10+" cols="+75+"></textarea>"));
```

And in some place I use this mp3 link from online to play an audio.

```
snd1 = new Audio("\""+$(mp33).val()+"\"");
snd1.play();
```

But It is not playing. If I hardcode the url it plays properly. Can anyone tell what is the problem with this passing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to either always escape and wrap attribute values in double quotes or use singe codes for the string delimter and inline double quotes.

At one point you write:

```
"<textarea name="+"mp3link"+"
```

Which actually becomes `<textarea name=mp3link` and then you escape the double quotes:  `id=\"mp33\"` which becomes `id="mp33"`. Its easier to just write `('<textarea att="value"')`.

Second, why dont you just create the audio and set the src via method?

```
snd1 = new Audio();
snd1.src = $(mp33).val();
snd1.play();
```

Does `$(mp33)` even exist?

Edit: I just saw you are using the textarea to get the value, but rather use the .text() method:

```
snd1 = new Audio();
    snd1.src = $('#mp33').text();
    snd1.play();
```

Comment: snd1 = new Audio();
snd1.src = $(mp33).val();
snd1.play();  not working $(mp33).val() returns without quotes and I guess src expects in quotes

Comment: src expects a string, .val() returns a string. as i said, since you are reading it from a textarea, try .text() instead of .val()